# I can't turn on extensions ubuntu 21.04 gnome 40

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, 21.04

After installing to ubuntu 21.04, all of my extensions is turn off and I can't turn it on.

Here are my extensions list:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I have tried to install gnome-shell-extension, and do a lot of things but I can't turn the extensions on

Also after installing 21.04, the tweaks tool doesn't have the extensions tab:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: You can try this one https://askubuntu.com/a/1343653/419088

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by installing Gnome Tweaks:

[image: Tweaks].

Not sure how it happened, but there was an extensions switch that was disabled:

[image: Disabled extension]

After enabling that, all of my extensions started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1036/extensions/) extension or the [Extension List](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3088/extension-list/) extension.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `chrome-gnome-shell` and then it worked (with Firefox).

Instruction found here: [GNOME Shell integration for Chrome Installation Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with gnome extensions and firefox/chrome installed as snaps. To resolve this, instead of the browser you can use the new "Extension manager" app.

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Then search for extension manager (blue puzzle piece icon) in your apps and enable the extensions you want.