# GNOME 40 in Ubuntu 21.04 does not show desktop wallpaper image

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, 21.04

I installed GNOME 40 on Ubuntu 21.04 using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shemgp/gnome-40 && sudo apt update
sudo apt install mutter gnome-shell gnome-session fonts-cantarell
sudo reboot
```

and then I changed to *GNOME on Xorg* in Desktop Manager (lock screen/GDM)

After I tried to change my wallpaper Image, I only see a black color!

[image: black desktop background]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Since gnome-tweak-tool won't work in gnome 40, here is how to install shell extensions in gnome 40.

1. Install the following packages using aptitude.

   chrome-gnome-shell and gnome-shell-extensions
2. install gnome shell extension add-on in google chrome.
3. go to gnome [shell extension page](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and install required extensions from there.
   note : "Customised workspaces" extension for changing background image.

[I have done it in debian 11 bullseye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXVrzFxY_NI)

Comment: In **U22.04**, this solution fails at [**extensions.gnome.org**](https://extensions.gnome.org/) with: "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected."

[Previous threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516422/gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is-not-detec) work through solutions for gnome-shell-extensions from multiple angles.

Answer (score 0):

According [to this](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/70505), it was after a bug on a recent commit.
**It was later fixed** [details here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/mtld81/update_to_gnome_shell_broke_wallpapers/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share).

Luckily, according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/oacpzr/gnome_40_desktop_background_is_always_black/), you must update gnome's gjs.

Then also do a full upgrade.
(**If you had just installed Gnome 40**) to make sure things go smooth.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gjs
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This fixed my Ubuntu 21.04 problem, and hopefully on your distro as well.

[here's a cool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxN6J.png)